# How insert parameter from java code into SQL query with regex?

Tags: java, sql, regex, oracle

When I build query I use parameters like:

`WAR_REPORT_CALLING_NUMBER = " and cal.calling_number = ? ";`

and from code I insert parametr instead `?` But now I need insert parameter into this string:

`WAR_REPORT_MSG1 = " AND regexp_like(pe.answer_recived,'^[^0-9]*[?][^0-9]*$') ";`

and this structure nor work. How do it?

Comment: assign the whole regexp expression as a parameter, e.g. `WAR_REPORT_MSG1 = " AND regexp_like(pe.answer_recived,?) ";`

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the regular expression to the parameter and change the condition with :

```
regexp_like(pe.answer_recived,?) ";
```